# Is there is a way to detect data sent from client to server in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs, webtest

I am working on a project with selenuim and phantomjs. I need to know after filling a form and clicking on the submit button if the data was sent to the server or if the data wasn't used. I tried to check the har file that I got after the submit button that was pressed, but this turned out to be a bad solution. 
Any other ways?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what language you are using, but maybe these will help:

[using proxy and selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11089952/8880880)

> Example of BrowserMob Proxy and Selenium
>
> ```
> from browsermobproxy import Server
>
>     server = Server("path/to/browsermob-proxy")
>     server.start()
>     proxy = server.create_proxy()
>
>     from selenium import webdriver
>     profile  = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
>     profile.set_proxy(proxy.selenium_proxy())
>     driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
>
>     proxy.new_har("google")
>     driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk")
>     proxy.har # returns a HAR JSON blob
>
>     proxy.stop()
>     driver.quit()
> ```

[post request and selenium](http://khachko.blogspot.com/2013/06/using-post-request-together-with.html)

> In this case you will have to:

1. Send post using Java
2. Add cookies
3. Send everything to web driver

> 